# Padding not Applying to Pseudo Element until Changing a Value in the Tools

Tags: html, css

I have no idea why, but (at least in Chrome anyway) I'm trying to separate the links with a pipe '|'. I can achieve this by adding padding of 0 10% - but whenever I reload the page, there is no padding, at least until I change the value of the padding and then back to 0 10%.

If you open this codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aXpRJv

It initially appears with no padding. Then if you change to 0 1% and then 0 10%, the padding shows correctly.

Why is this happening, and how can it be fixed? Thanks for any help

```css
#headerHomeLogIn:after {
    content: '|';
    padding: 0 10%;
}
#headerHomeLogIn { white-space: nowrap }

#headerAccountLinks {
    background: lightgreen;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 25%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerAccountLinks">
  <span id="headerHomeLogIn">Log In</span>
  <span>Sign Up</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `px` instead of percentages like this:

(I added a `margin: 0 10px;` to space it evenly)

```css
#headerHomeLogIn:after {
    content: '|';
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
#headerHomeLogIn { white-space: nowrap }

#headerAccountLinks {
    background: lightgreen;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 25%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerAccountLinks">
  <span id="headerHomeLogIn">Log In</span>
  <span>Sign Up</span>
</div>
```

Comment: this seems to work - any idea why padding doesn't work? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pGRxxM

Comment: I'm not sure why the percentage isn't working. It's just my opinion that you can control the spacing better by using padding/margin pixels and media queries.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by adding `display:inline-block;`

```
#headerHomeLogIn:after {
  content: '|';
  padding: 0 10%; 
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: that makes no difference to me - load this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mvRzGx - you have to change something again